# After filled input details of opportunity when click on save it should redirect to the list page of Opportunity

Tags: visualforce

My question is i have button  when click on new opportunity button new page of opportunity should open on which i need to fill details and when i will click on save button it will take redirect to the list page of opportunity where i can edit and delete record that i created .So i am using standard controller on second page for opportunity input and when click on save Opportunity detail page is open what should i do to redirect it to a list page of Opportunity with standard controller.

Comment: Are you using standard save method? In this case you need extension with custom save method.

Answer (score 0):

public PageReference save() {
 Schema.DescribeSObjectResult result = oppurtunity.SObjectType.getDescribe();
 PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + result.getKeyPrefix());
 pageRef.setRedirect(true);
 return pageRef;
}